# How do you configure PyCharm to run py.test with command-line options like -s?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I figured out how to run py.test files from PyCharm:

- Run/Debug configurations
- in the Python tests category, click the "+" button to add a new configuration
- choose `py.test`
- enter the full path for the Target script and the working directory

but I can't seem to add the `-s` option to allow my test script to run with standard output not captured and hidden. (I tried `-s` under interpreter options but it appears not to do anything.)

How can I enable `-s`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

D'oh, I figured it out after all:

[image]

You add it in the py.tests Options area of the Run/Edit configuration dialog.

Comment: To expand: if you want to configure defaults (so PyCharm auto-sets this when it auto-creates launch configs), there is separate `Defaults` category under `Run/Debug Edit Configurations`. Just set it there under `Python tests > py.test`.

Comment: Still won't work for me.  I'm trying to add "*.py", which means to look in all py files for functions named test_*.  It gets swallowed by the test running scripts.

Comment: Could you show how you got to this screen? I can't seem to find it. Edit Nevermind. Found it as well

Comment: How can we configure similar setup in Eclipse with PyDev plugin?

Comment: @zeal -- no idea, ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @JasonS - yep, raised it as separate question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475209/configuring-python-project-in-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment64357987_38475209) - adding the link here for the benefit of getting some expert(s) attention!!!

Comment: This does not make much sense as is quite likely for the user to want to run pytest against its entire project, not a specific file. Target parameter seems to be mandatory. Still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Where is this magical Options area? I see: "Parameters" and "Additional Arguments". I see "Interpreter Options" - but that is for something else.