# Configuring Python project in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pycharm, pydev

Actually I'm trying to use a python framework in Eclipse (with PyDev plugin) - the framework was designed in PyCharm IDE where we do some configuration as in the screenshot below:

[image]

I've tried searching for reference links, but no luck so far. So can someone help me on how to configure **Target, Keywords, Options** parameter in Eclipse?

******** ADDING SOME ADDITIONAL INFO ********

Herewith, I'm adding some basic snippet as instructed -

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.test
def test_method():
    print "test method"

class TestClass:
    def test_one(self):
        x = "this"
        assert 'h' in x

    def test_two(self):
        x = "hello"
        assert 'o' in x
```

It's working fine when I try to run it through command prompt using the following command

> $ py.test -k "test"
>
> ============================= test session starts ============================= platform win32 -- Python 2.7.12 -- pytest-2.5.1 plugins: xdist, xdist, xdist collected 3 items
>
> test_sample.py ...
>
> ========================== 3 passed in 0.05 seconds ===========================

But it's not working when I try to run it through Eclipse PyDev, please be informed I've changed the PyUnit test runner option to Py.test runner as specified in [blog](http://pydev.blogspot.se/2010/12/improved-unittest-support-in-pydev.html). I have also tried to provide the `-k "test"` option in **Run > Run Configurations >  Argument**s, but getting some abrupt exception as below - please help!

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256\pysrc\runfiles.py",
>   line 241, in 
>       main()   File "D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256\pysrc\runfiles.py",
>   line 233, in main
>       return pytest.main(argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\config.py", line 18, in main
>       config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\config.py", line 62, in
>   _prepareconfig
>       pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 376, in **call**
>       return self._docall(methods, kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 387, in _docall
>       res = mc.execute()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 288, in execute
>       res = method(**kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 25, in
>   pytest_cmdline_parse
>       config = **multicall**.execute()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 288, in execute
>       res = method(**kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\config.py", line 617, in
>   pytest_cmdline_parse
>       self.parse(args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\config.py", line 710, in parse
>       self._preparse(args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\config.py", line 686, in
>   _preparse
>       self.pluginmanager.consider_preparse(args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 185, in
>   consider_preparse
>       self.consider_pluginarg(opt2)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 195, in
>   consider_pluginarg
>       self.import_plugin(arg)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 214, in
>   import_plugin
>       mod = importplugin(modname)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages_pytest\core.py", line 269, in
>   importplugin
>       **import**(importspec)   File "D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256\pysrc_pydev_runfiles\pydev_runfiles_pytest2.py",
>   line 284, in 
>       @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hookimpl'

Comment: It seems PyDev puts all the options in one place; see http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html, which also links to the py.test docs.

Comment: No it didn't workout... i've tried updating like _-k=sanity --project=city1 --env=city1_sit --translation=ct_... but got some error like **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hookimpl'**

Comment: Then please [edit] the question with a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I understand your ask, but to be honest I'm not that much expert to shrink the framework to minimal snippet and share for reference. But my question is similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868516/how-do-you-configure-pycharm-to-run-py-test-with-command-line-options-like-s/27868557?noredirect=1#comment64382382_27868557), there he asked for PyCharm. It may also give similar details, but at least in different way!

Comment: You could at the very least provide a traceback to tell us *where* that error gets thrown. If it's just from py.test, before reaching your tests, none of the code you've actually written is relevant. But I can't tell that from here, you need to try setting up a clean project and moving in minimal code until it replicates the error. Indeed you should have *already done this*, that's basic debugging.

Comment: Actually there is some known issue in PyCharm debug for us, so I'm trying to use PyDev. So the framework is intact and it's working perfectly fine in PyCharm. Definitely I'll try to figure out minimal code util for reference, but I think following command may give you my expectation: _py.test --project=city1 --env=city1_sit --translation=ct -k "sanity" city1\tests\_ command line would trigger the execution in our framework through win terminal. Looking to configure these parameters in _Eclipse>Run>Run configurations_ appropriately. I'm confused with multiple tabs and options available there!

Comment: @jonrsharpe - added some additional information as suggested, please check and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm, can you update your pytest version and retry that? Which pytest version are you using?

I.e. it seems PyDev is now requiring pytest 2.7 onwards (hookwrapper: executing around other hooks is New in version 2.7 from: http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html).

As a note, pytest 2.7 is from Mar 26, 2015, so, it's already relatively old.

Comment: Yep, perfect it worked. Previously I had pytest 2.5.1 and now upgraded to latest one. Could you please confirm where could I specify the command line option value in PyDev? I'm trying something like **pytest.config.getoption("test")**, any suggestion? While tying this I also noted that PyDev throws error stating that **Undefined variable from import: config**.